# Kotlin run scope function returning different data type

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun getStringFromSampleObject(sampleObj: SampleObj): String = sampleObj.run {
        age = 2
        title = "newTitle"
        isValid = true
    }.toString()

val returnedValue =
            Playground().getStringFromSampleObject(SampleObj(age = 1, title = "title", isValid = false))
        Log.e(TAG, "Play, returned string is$returnedValue")
```

I try to print the return value from the function `getStringFromSampleObject()` but the value of `returnedValue` is `kotlin.Unit`. I expect the string value instead.

Comment: `run()` returns the result of the lambda expression. If you are expecting the scope function to return `sampleObj`, you want `apply()`, not `run()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apply rather than run. It will return object. For better understanding you can refer to this link for [Scope Functions](http://%5Chttps://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html)

Comment: `let` is equivalent to `run` returns the last expression. He should probably go with `apply` which gives you receiver like `run` but returns the object it was applied on.

Comment: But as far as I understood, apply is used to return the same object right? Here In my example, I have a sample object as input and want string back. So should I not go with run or with because I understood that run or with returns different object or data types